# Does OpenLayer provide SDK to do asset tracking in realtime

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I need to develop a web application to monitor cars in realtime.  The cars position must be refreshed every 2 or 3 seconds to know the position of each car in the city.

If not,  Is there another free alternative?  Google SDK is too much expensive.

Thanks.

Victor

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your detailed requirements. OpenLayers can definitely be used to visualise almost any geospatial data. There is no API for 'realtime data' because the realtime aspect is completely out of OpenLayers' control. It's up to you to manage realtime connection, and simply pass updated data into OL, which will work perfectly.

If you don't already have a database or tech stack, I'd consider [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/database/) to handle the realtime element.

Alternatives to OpenLayers are [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/), [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)

Comment: Hi,  you are right.  Location (GOS coordinates) come from CellPhone GPS  that ahve installed an APP that send every 2 or 3 seconds the "location" of the car. So I need just draw these "all" locations in the OL map.  Is this correct?  Thanks,

Comment: Sorry:  "GOS coordinates" should be "GPS coordinates".